# How do I block large ranges of IPs independent of server-specific options?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, apache2, iptables

I got tired of being trolled by international users constantly probing around the edges of my SSH server, and while [DenyHosts](http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net) was a good starting point for managing SSH access, I decided I wanted something slightly different.

After all - what if you aren't running SSH? What if you have a web or FTP server? What if you run a public Minecraft server? What if you're running all of them? What if you're running none of them but use a linux-based router? Apache users may consider using `.htaccess` rules for web access, which is also a good choice, or configure `modsecurity` to block user agent strings permanently while `mod_evasive` blocks abusive IPs on a temporary basis (fairly useful against spiders and bot farms), but isn't there something a little more universal, which can be applied to all potential configurations and situations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter `iptables` and [Wizcrafts](http://www.wizcrafts.net/iptables-blocklists.html). Not every Linux system comes configured with `libwrap`, and `hosts.deny` doesn't always get consulted, or gives unexpected results if you have a problem with your config.

There have been many arguments among sysadmins who either support or decry `tcpwrappers`. Some say there's nothing quite as spectacular as a finely tuned `/etc/hosts.deny` to keep undesirables at bay while others say it isn't the paragon of security that it was back in the '90s, especially when it comes to blacklisting.

I don't want to get into any of that - it's too much like the *Star Wars **versus** Star Trek* circle of never-ending arguments. I just want to make you aware (if you weren't already) of the differing opinions. You can draw your own conclusions.

Because `denyhosts` requires your ssh server to be configured with the `tcp_wrappers` support option enabled, it makes some admins uncomfortable (I personally don't mind it however). And as mentioned earlier, `denyhosts` doesn't even do any good if you aren't running SSH.

So, what was my Universal Solution? Pretty simple. I took all the blocklists painstakingly maintained by Wizcrafts (well worth it - his blocklists are *fantastic!*) and saved them into a single text file, then wrote this shell script to filter the comments out of the list and use iptables to block the IP ranges of known offenders from around the world:

```
#/bin/bash
# |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | rangeblock.sh - reads a list of IP ranges, filters non-numeric entries, then configures
# | iptables to block what's left
# | 
# | Maybe it's cutting corners to just check the first character, but iptables will throw
# | out anything it doesn't like anyway, and the loop won't break on errors
# | 
# | Hint: runs best as root
# |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

file="wizcrafts.txt" # Change to a command-line option for more flexibility

while read line; do
    echo " "
    echo "Current Entry: $line"
    if [[ ${line:0:1} == [0-9]* ]]; then        
        echo "$line is a valid IP range. Added to iptables block list."
        iptables -I INPUT -s $line -j DROP
    else
        echo "$line was skipped. Not a valid IP or range."
    fi
done <"$file"
```

Now, most of the offending traffic is dropped before it even gets to my SSH server, and anything does that DOES get through is handled by `denyhosts`.

Nothing is ever 100%, and this doesn't replace smart practices (like not allowing root to login through ssh), but it makes things much easier to deal with.

Or, at least it did for me. Interesting side effect - my system and network performance improved by nearly 30% after I implemented this.